# Making Text Font Bold

Tags: text, fonts, vb6

When I try to make the text font bold with

```
ActiveSheet.Range("C2:G2").Select 
With Selection
   .Merge
   .Value = "Dealer Commission Rate"
   .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
   .WrapText = True
   .Font.Name = "Arial"
   .Font.Size = 11
   .Font.Bolt = True
End With
```

in VB6, I keep getting this warning:

> "The selection contains multiple data value. Merging into one cell
>   will keep the upper-left most data only"

Another problem because of the line .`Font.Bolt = True`,

```
error#:438 "Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

How can I suppress the warning and get the text font bolt?

Comment: Maybe `.Font.Bold`?

Comment: How can you even write .Bolt, when there is IntelliSense?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing

`.Font.Bolt = True`

Try
`.Font.Bold = True`